# Unable to play hls live stream on chrome using videojs

Tags: video.js, adobe-media-server

I am trying to stream and play HLS on chrome using videojs player but I am getting a cors error. Even though I have added Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" in httpd.conf file . In adobe media HTTP server's  error logs I am getting

Wed Apr 28 12:01:06 2021] [warn] bootstrap path is in event file is empty for event:livepkgr/events/*definst*/liveevent stream name:livestream
[Wed Apr 28 12:01:06 2021] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Media Server 5/webroot/hls-live, referer: http://localhost:81/

This is the configuration I am using for adobe flash media encoder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<flashmedialiveencoder_profile>
    <preset>
        <name>Custom</name>
        <description></description>
    </preset>
    <capture>
        <video>
        <device>HP Truevision HD</device>
        <crossbar_input>0</crossbar_input>
        <frame_rate>30.00</frame_rate>
        <size>
            <width>320</width>
            <height>240</height>
        </size>
        </video>
    </capture>
    <process>
        <video>
        <preserve_aspect></preserve_aspect>
        </video>
    </process>
    <encode>
        <video>
        <format>H.264</format>
        <datarate>200;</datarate>
        <outputsize>320x240;</outputsize>
        <advanced>
            <profile>Main</profile>
            <level>3.1</level>
            <keyframe_frequency>5 Seconds</keyframe_frequency>
        </advanced>
        <autoadjust>
            <enable>false</enable>
            <maxbuffersize>1</maxbuffersize>
            <dropframes>
            <enable>false</enable>
            </dropframes>
            <degradequality>
            <enable>false</enable>
            <minvideobitrate></minvideobitrate>
            <preservepfq>false</preservepfq>
            </degradequality>
        </autoadjust>
        </video>
    </encode>
    <restartinterval>
        <days></days>
        <hours></hours>
        <minutes>30</minutes>
    </restartinterval>
    <reconnectinterval>
        <attempts></attempts>
        <interval></interval>
    </reconnectinterval>
    <output>
        <rtmp>
        <url>rtmp://localhost/livepkgr</url>
        <backup_url></backup_url>
        <stream>livestream?adbe-live-event=liveevent&amp;adbe-record-mode=record</stream>
        </rtmp>
    </output>
    <metadata>
        <entry>
        <key>author</key>
        <value></value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
        <key>copyright</key>
        <value></value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
        <key>description</key>
        <value></value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
        <key>keywords</key>
        <value></value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
        <key>rating</key>
        <value></value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
        <key>title</key>
        <value></value>
        </entry>
    </metadata>
    <preview>
        <video>
        <input>
            <zoom>100%</zoom>
        </input>
        <output>
            <zoom>100%</zoom>
        </output>
        </video>
        <audio></audio>
    </preview>
</flashmedialiveencoder_profile>
```